# macro interpetation of Gibbs energy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I will create two scenarios for the gibbs energy and try to derive it energetically. One of them I will have a problem with the other comes along fine according to me.

Case 1:

If $dp=0$  $dH=dQ-pdV+pdV+Vdp=dQ$. Then you can use the fact that the surroundings change in Q is dH so you can obtain:

$$\Delta G=\Delta H-T\Delta S=\Delta Q-T \Delta S=T \Delta S_{surr}-T \Delta S_{sys}$$ Energetically this could add up because the Q can be used to volume expansion since dT=0

Case 2:

Gibbs is also used when $dp \neq 0$  we have $dG=dH-TdS-SdT$ $$dQ-pdV+pdV+Vdp-TdS-SdT=TdS+Vdp-TdS-SdT=Vdp-SdT$$

if $dT=0$ $dG=Vdp$

My problem is how to make this to add up energetically. I could say that if we choose the same approach as in case 1 then since dp=0 for the surroundings one could again use entropy for the surroundings but then one would have to have the relation $\Delta H_{surr}=\Delta H_{sys}$ which means that $T\Delta S_{
surr}=\Delta Q_{sys}+V_{sys} \Delta p_{sys}$
 I could write $T\Delta S_{
surr}=\Delta Q_{sys}+nR \Delta T_{sys}$ but I am not sure how this would explain the energetically transfer that leads to equilibrium?

Comment: In Case 1, where did you get that $\Delta G=\Delta H-T\Delta S$?

Comment: Is not that the most normal definition of gibbs free energy when dT=0?

Comment: Yes, but I hadn't noticed that you said that $\Delta T=0$.  Also, T of the system is the same as T of the surroundings only if the process is carried out reversibly.

Comment: @fisher garry It it not clear to me what is the question in case 2. You have derived a correct equation, $dG = - S dT + p dV$. What do you mean when you ask "explain the energetically transfer that leads to equilibrium"?